# Reordering columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm populating `DataGridView` (Winforms) through code and biding rows from `DataTable`. Also property for reordering columns is set to true. 
If I reorder columns and I want to get new order of columns the order is always same. It means if first columns is named `"ID"` and last columns is named `"Price"`, by moving `ID` in place of `Price` and `Price` in place of `ID` and if I want to list columns using this piece of code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= dgAnalyse.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dgAnalyse.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dgAnalyse.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                }
            }
```

I will get: ID, Price not Price, ID.

Is it possible to get list of new order of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I reorder columns and I want to get new order of columns the order
>   is always same.

When you change the order of the columns at runtime using the  `DataGridView.AllowUserToOrderColumns` functionality, **it won't change the order of `DataGridView.Columns` collection**. Just the [`DisplayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) property of the columns will change.

If you want to iterate into the columns **in display order**, you could use `Link`:

**C#**

```
var q = from c in this.DataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()orderby c.DisplayIndex select c;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in q) 
{
    if (column.Visible == true) 
    {
    Console.WriteLine(column.HeaderText.ToString());
    }
}
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim q = From c In Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() Order By c.DisplayIndex Select c
For Each column In q
        If column.Visible Then
            Console.WriteLine(column.HeaderText.ToString())
        End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex%28VS.80%29.aspx) property of the individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how to use the `DisplayIndex` property in your specific case, try this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dgAnalyse.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dgAnalyse.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dgAnalyse.Columns[dgAnalyse.Columns[i].DisplayIndex].HeaderText);
                }
            }
```